# Write junit test cases for the Future callback

Tags: java, junit, callback, async-await, completable-future

Can someone help to write JUnit test for below section of code especially the add callback part?
I am not sure how to write unit test cases for the Listenablefuture with the callback

```
    private void handleResponse(final ListenableFuture<UserRecordResult> response, CompletableFuture future) {

        Futures.addCallback(response, new FutureCallback<UserRecordResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@Nonnull Throwable throwable) {

                future.completeExceptionally(new Exception("Fail to put record" + throwable.getMessage()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UserRecordResult result) {
                if(result.isSuccessful()) {
                    future.complete(true);
                } else {
                    future.completeExceptionally(new Exception("Fail to put record"));
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Just a thought.. kinesisProducer is not yours. So it should be mocked and you will handle the response part giving either a success completable future or a failure!

Comment: I am not sure how to write unit test for the void method handleResponse

Comment: the way your function is set is not rly helpful for testing. You can change it so instead of using anonymous class you can turn it into actual class and write tests for this. so you have onFailure and onSuccess covered. as for handleResponse itself it use `Futures.addCallback` which is not your code / responsibility to test ! Now if you really want to see this line also green you will have to "mock" Futures.addCallback with something like powermock

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can test by stubbing `ListeneableFuture` and `CompletableFuture` in following manner:

```
@Test
public void completeExceptionallyOnCallbackFailure() {
    ListenableFuture<UserRecordResult> failureResponse = Futures.immediateFailedFuture(new RuntimeException());
    CompletableFuture future = new CompletableFuture();

    handleResponse(failureResponse, future);

    assertThat(future.isCompletedExceptionally(), equalTo(true));
}

@Test
public void completeExceptionallyIfUserRecordResultIsNotSuccessful() {
    UserRecordResult mockResult = Mockito.mock(UserRecordResult.class);
    Mockito.when(mockResult.isSuccessful()).thenReturn(false);

    ListenableFuture<UserRecordResult> failureResponse = Futures.immediateFuture(mockResult);
    CompletableFuture future = new CompletableFuture();

    handleResponse(failureResponse, future);

    assertThat(future.isCompletedExceptionally(), equalTo(true));
}

@Test
public void completeSuccessfully() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    UserRecordResult mockResult = Mockito.mock(UserRecordResult.class);
    Mockito.when(mockResult.isSuccessful()).thenReturn(true);

    ListenableFuture<UserRecordResult> successResponse = Futures.immediateFuture(mockResult);
    CompletableFuture future = new CompletableFuture();

    handleResponse(successResponse, future);

    assertThat(future.get(), equalTo(true));
}
```

Also, you can assert actual error messages by using `assertj`:

```
@Test
public void verifyMessageIfCompletedExceptionallyAfterUserRecordResultIsNotSuccessful() {
    UserRecordResult mockResult = Mockito.mock(UserRecordResult.class);
    Mockito.when(mockResult.isSuccessful()).thenReturn(false);

    ListenableFuture<UserRecordResult> failureResponse = Futures.immediateFuture(mockResult);
    CompletableFuture future = new CompletableFuture();

    Assertions.assertThatThrownBy(() -> {
        handleResponse(failureResponse, future);
        future.get();
    })
    .isInstanceOf(Exception.class)
    .hasMessage("java.lang.Exception: Fail to put record");
}
```

Comment: How can I handle this if I am running Futures.addCallBack on a different thread.